# Zoom camera towards 3d world mouse coordinates

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm a little stuck on trying to zoom my camera view towards my mouse coordinates in the 3D space.

I have the 3D coordinates of the mouse.

My zoom works as is just to zoom to the screen center, but I want to be able to zoom like you do in Sketchup.

```
void CCamera::OnMouseWheel(float zDelta) {
    Position -= Reference;

    if (zDelta < 0 && length(Position) < 500.0f) {
        Position += Position * 0.1f;
    }

    if (zDelta > 0 && length(Position) > 0.05f) {
        Position -= Position * 0.1f;
    }

    Position += Reference;

    CalculateViewMatrix();
}

void CCamera::CalculateViewMatrix() {
    ViewMatrix = mat4x4(X.x, Y.x, Z.x, 0.0f, X.y, Y.y, Z.y, 0.0f, X.z, Y.z, Z.z, 0.0f, -dot(X, Position), -dot(Y, Position), -dot(Z, Position), 1.0f);
    ViewMatrixInverse = inverse(ViewMatrix);
    ViewProjectionMatrix = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix;
    ViewProjectionMatrixInverse = ViewMatrixInverse * ProjectionMatrixInverse;
}

void CCamera::Move(const vec3 &Movement) {
    Position += Movement;
    Reference += Movement;

    CalculateViewMatrix();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pure opengl zoom camera to mouse pos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102726/pure-opengl-zoom-camera-to-mouse-pos)

Comment: Why do you repeat your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102726/pure-opengl-zoom-camera-to-mouse-pos)?

Comment: @Ripi2 i changed what i was asking, an dont think anyone was looking at it.